# How to embed SWF files stored outside web root

Tags: php, html, flash

I have a page which displays SWF files uploaded by the users.
For security purpose I store them outside root, but how can I now include those files in a webpage.
I have already tried readfile() and file_get_contents() methods, both doesnt work.

Comment: Can you generate the url of the SWF file and use that to embed them. If the file is outside root folder then possibly that cannot be done. In that case you can maybe create another site/domain/sub-domain just for hosting the files/images(something like files.yourdomain.com) and use that for generating the required URL which you can then use for embedding the files.

Comment: Telepathy offline, please post code.